# Update based on previous value SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-update, logic

I need to Update these NULL Values:

```
PK |  CODE
---+-------
1  |   20
2  |   NULL
3  |   NULL
4  |   30
5  |   NULL
6  |   NULL
7  |   NULL
8  |   40
9  |   NULL
```

Like this:

```
PK   |   CODE
-----+------------
1    |    20
2    |    20
3    |    20
4    |    30
5    |    30
6    |    30
7    |    30
8    |    40
9    |    40
```

It should always be based on the last minimum value.

I have tried the code below, but it just updates the first row before the one who had value at the beginning.

### **QUERY**

```
UPDATE TT 
SET CODE = (SELECT CODE 
FROM #TSPV_TEMP T2 with(nolock)
WHERE T2.KEY = (tt.KEY -1))
FROM #TSPV_TEMP TT with (nolock)
WHERE tt.CODE IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
UPDATE TT 
    SET CODE = (SELECT TOP 1 CODE
                FROM #TSPV_TEMP T2 with(nolock)
                WHERE T2.KEY < tt.KEY AND
                      CODE IS NOT NULL
                ORDER BY KEY DESC
               )
    FROM #TSPV_TEMP TT with (nolock)
    where tt.CODE IS NULL;
```

Note the differences in the subquery.  This looks for the previous non-NULL value for `CODE` for the update.

Comment: Thank you, @GordonLinoff, actually it almost worked. I just had to do a little change: ((T2.KEY < (tt.KEY -1) OR (T2.KEY = (tt.KEY -1)). Because it wasn't updating the first null row.

Answer (score 0):

```
update tbl
   set code =
       (select code
          from tbl x
         where x.pk = (select max(y.pk)
                         from tbl y
                        where y.pk < tbl.pk
                          and code is not null))
 where code is null;
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3803d/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Another way using a derived table which for every pk with a null code contains the maximum lesser pk with a non-null code.

```
update t1
set t1.code = t3.code
from tt t1 join
    (select t1.pk, max(t2.pk) max_pk
    from tt t1
    join tt t2 on t1.pk > t2.pk
    and t2.code is not null
    and t1.code is null
    group by t1.pk) t2 on t2.pk = t1.pk
join tt t3 on t3.pk = t2.max_pk
```